# Increase allowed redirects in browser?

Tags: php, redirect, browser

I have a script that uses a ton of redirects.  About half way through the process I get an error message in the browser saying:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://localhost/....... has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Is there a way to increase the allowed redirects in the browser?

Comment: U can't , Try use javascript(document.location="") or meta(refresh) redirects

Comment: I doubt if you should rely on browser-specific setting. Why not send across fewer redirects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firefox, navigate to `about:config` in the address bar.  Search for `network.http.redirection-limit` and increase the value to your desired value.

This setting in Firefox controls how many redirects it will accept before it stops following them.

Comment: True, if that is the case then its not possible.

Comment: No, I'm just looking to change the setting in the browser.  I couldn't find about -> config.  Could be a little more specific in how to find the option?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry edited it, you put the `about:config` in the browser address bar.